# How to save result return from a google map API respond?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I got some problems

I wanna get my current location and assign it to a variable, but it doesnt work. I dont know why

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var result;
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    result = position;
  });

  // do something with result
})
```

the prroblem is: position cannot be assigned to result. Are there any ways to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous function receiving the results from Google Maps is called asynchronously to the rest of the execution logic: the "do something with result" part is executed first.

Proper solution: put the "do something with result" part inside the anonymous function, ie:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var result;  
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    // do something with result
    });
})
```

Comment: but position is local variable, just available inside navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition function. i wanna store it into a global variable so that i can access its content everywhere i want ( I am using EJS to render data, and the View is separate from the Logic) Can u show me the way to store position?
thanks